# Why use UIDocument over standard Archiving

Tags: objective-c, ios

I have used `UIDocument`, but I don't understand the advantage over using Archiving? Assuming you don't want to use iCloud.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

From Apple's docs: http://developer.apple.com/library/ios/#documentation/uikit/reference/UIDocument_Class/UIDocument/UIDocument.html

> Applications that make use of UIDocument and its underlying
>   architecture get many benefits for their documents:
>
> - Asynchronous reading and writing of data on a background queue. Your
>     application's responsiveness to users is thus unaffected while reading
>     and writing operations are taking place.
> - Coordinated reading and
>     writing of document files that is automatically integrated with cloud
>     services. Support for discovering conflicts between different versions
>     of a document (if that occurs).
> - Safe-saving of document data by
>     writing data first to a temporary file and then replacing the current
>     document file with it.
> - Automatic saving of document data at opportune
>     moments; this mechanism includes support for dealing with suspend
>     behaviors.

You get nice integration with NSUndoManager, too